# VB.NET MyApplication equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

in my vb.Net Project I have used below code for setting date format of MyApplication

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        Dim newculture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone()
        newculture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        newculture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/"
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newculture
End Sub
```

> How I can do this in c#??

Comment: what kind of application is your dll or exe. type.

Comment: application type is exe

Comment: open program.cs file and add the below code. into static main method.

Comment: problem solved by the answer of Mr. John Willemse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `Program.cs` you have `static void Main()`, where you can initialize application settings.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";

        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```

Comment: The question is how to change the dateformat of the application, you are deducting that he will need to change the format before the application start, but is totally legit for example to change inside the form load or in another parts of the code if you are working with multiple cultures.

Comment: No, he shows us the `Application_Startup` method, which in VB .NET runs when the application is starting up and initializing. He uses it to set some culture specific settings before the GUI is shown and his question is how he can do the same in C#.

Comment: By the way, downvoting a correct, accepted answer because I downvoted your _incorrect_ answer is very childish.

Comment: By the way, I voted down when your answer was showing the comment "// put the code here" (before your last edit) instead of ACTUALLY change the datetime format.

Answer (score -2):

try online converter for your help like below.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

your code converted from the same.

```
private void MyApplication_Startup(object sender, Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo newculture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    newculture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    newculture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newculture;
}
```

Comment: This is converting the VB to C#, which is not the question.

Comment: so you just want to set the culture values at you application startup ?

Comment: what all you need to do is just move this code into you main method the entry point of your application.

Comment: That's what the OP asks ;)